# Why my query become too slow when number of records increased

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

I have an insert statement in SQL Server.

I tried it for a smaller subset, was fast

increased the number to 1milllion records and was fast 1 min 10 sec

now I doubled it and it seems stuck it has been running for 10 min now and no results

I included the Plan when it was 5 min.

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r15MPuC5u

maybe someone can tell me how to improve the process.

PS. I added non clustered index on Tag (RepID).

Tag(iiD) is a primary Key

Reps(RepID) is a primary Key.

While I am writing this. the process finished at 11:47

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJd9uOCcu

Here is my code

```
insert into R3..Tags (iID,DT,RepID,Tag,xmiID,iBegin,iEnd,Confidence,Polarity,Uncertainty,Conditional,Generic,HistoryOf,CodingScheme,Code,CUI,TUI,PreferredText,ValueBegin,ValueEnd,Value,Deleted,sKey,RepType)
SELECT T.iID,T.DT,T.RepID,T.Tag,T.xmiID,T.iBegin,T.iEnd,T.Confidence,T.Polarity,T.Uncertainty,T.Conditional,T.Generic,T.HistoryOf,T.CodingScheme,T.Code,T.CUI,T.TUI,T.PreferredText,T.ValueBegin,T.ValueEnd,T.Value,T.Deleted,T.sKey,R.RepType
FROM Recovery..tags  T inner join Recovery..Reps R on T.RepID = R.RepID
where T.iID between 2000001 and 4000000
```

Comment: is "Recovery" a linked server?

Comment: Those are 3-part names, so they should all be databases within the current instance. Making assumptions but `Recovery..tags` is the same as `Recovery.dbo.tags` - which we can see in the plan details. And the execution plan says 2 million rows, not 1 million.

Comment: @SMor exactly they are 3 DBs in the same instance. they all live in my laptop

Comment: Try to get a parallel insert, at the moment the actual insert is not parallelized. Trace Flag 610 may be required, along with a `TABLOCK` hint on the target table. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#insert--select also https://sqlperformance.com/2019/05/sql-performance/minimal-logging-empty-clustered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(can't fit in comment , put it here)

I think , there is pretty much nothing you can do about this , depending on your hardware , 11 min  can be actually not bad , in the execution plan , I can see everything looks ok.

but for your information , bottleneck in that insert statement is to read data from T"Recovery..tags" table, which took 07 minutes of your query time.(It's used full scan which is ok considering it needs to read 2 million rows and return a lot of columns)

so the only thing you can do is to find a way to speed up reading from linked server "Recovery".
linked servers are usually the source of poor performance, specially huge data ,which can be due to poor network or busy network , etc ...

anyways one solution is :

- pull data from linked server into a table into R3 server ( directly) with server in middle.which depends on your scenario you can
- change your query to be against that table

this can significantly improve your query time